# How to configure mouse enhance pointer precision programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, configuration, mouse

How to configure mouse enhance pointer precision programmatically in C++?
I know that have some useful commands like SystemParametersInfo, for speed, ...

```
int x = 15;
```

> SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, NULL, reinterpret_cast(x),SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE );

... but I cannot find enhance precision----

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) for the `SystemParametersInfo` function and `SPI_SETMOUSE`:

> Sets the two mouse threshold values and the mouse acceleration. The `pvParam` parameter must point to an array of three integers that specifies these values. See [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) for further information.

So you need an array containing 3 values, and you specify a pointer to that array as the `pvParam` parameter when calling `SystemParametersInfo`.

Since all you care about is changing the acceleration (the last value), you probably want to retain the *current* values for the first two, the mouse threshold values. Do that by calling `SystemParametersInfo` with the `SPI_GETMOUSE` flag to obtain those values, then modifying the last one (the acceleration), and then calling `SystemParametersInfo` again, this time with the `SPI_SETMOUSE` flag.

Sample code (without recommended error checking):

```
// Turns mouse acceleration on/off by calling the SystemParametersInfo function.
// When mouseAccel is TRUE, mouse acceleration is turned on; FALSE for off.
void SetMouseAcceleration(BOOL mouseAccel)
{
    int mouseParams[3];

    // Get the current values.
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSE, 0, mouseParams, 0);

    // Modify the acceleration value as directed.
    mouseParams[2] = mouseAccel;

    // Update the system setting.
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSE, 0, mouseParams, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
```

And you probably already know this, but there are too many badly-behaved applications out there for me not to mention it just in case. **If you're doing this in your application, be sure to save the original value so that you can restore it when your app is closed!** This is just basic etiquette when you're modifying system-wide settings.

Comment: Have anyone checked if setting the threshold values makes any difference at all? I did try modifying them and I don't notice any change in the way the cursor moves.

Answer (score 1):

'Enhance pointer precision' is an on/off acceleration option.

The `SPI_SETMOUSE` parameter for SystemParametersInfo will adjust this setting.

I can't tell you exactly how the acceleration values are affected, but if you `SPI_GETMOUSE` and display the values with the setting on and off you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

[This discussion](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic9593.html) has a bit more information. It has a macro which seems to do what you're looking for. It should be pretty straightforward to convert to C++; it's just a couple DLL calls.