# Programmatically disabling mouse acceleration in Windows

Tags: windows, language-agnostic

When I use my laptop's trackpad I want acceleration on, but when I have a mouse plugged in I normally want it off. I couldn't find a fast way to make the change, so I'd like to make a simple application that lets you switch it on or off at the press of a button. Does anyone know of a way to disable or enable mouse acceleration in Windows either via some sort of COM or system function (any language), or a command line program?

For clarification, here is the setting I'd like to change:

[image: Mouse acceleration]

Comment: similar question with a however less general scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737775/toggle-enhance-pointer-precision

Comment: and one for cpp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902477/how-to-configure-mouse-enhance-pointer-precision-programatically?lq=1