# Toggle Enhance pointer precision

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, mouse-cursor

We are basically creating a control panel applet. We need to toggle "Enhance pointer precision" in Mouse Properties.
To do so we need to call `SystemParametersInfo` with `SPI_GETMOUSE`. It has an array of 3 elements as its third parameter. I'm new to PInvoke and I've tried many signatures but so far no luck. Here is what I've tried for the signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref long[] vparam, SPIF fWinIni);  

static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref long[] vparam, SPIF fWinIni);
```

None of the above worked for me and here's the exception I'm getting:
`System.AccessViolationException`: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
While searching I came up with [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?3302-Get-Set-Mouse-speed) which is in VB.

**Solution:** Thanks to [GWLlosa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24738152/2550529) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9052357/2550529) I came up with the solution:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfoGet(uint action, uint param, IntPtr vparam, SPIF fWinIni);
public const UInt32 SPI_GETMOUSE = 0x0003;
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfoSet(uint action, uint param, IntPtr vparam, SPIF fWinIni);
public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSE = 0x0004;
public static bool ToggleEnhancePointerPrecision(bool b)
{
    int[] mouseParams = new int[3];
    // Get the current values.
    SystemParametersInfoGet(SPI_GETMOUSE, 0, GCHandle.Alloc(mouseParams, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject(), 0);
    // Modify the acceleration value as directed.
    mouseParams[2] = b ? 1 : 0;
    // Update the system setting.
    return SystemParametersInfoSet(SPI_SETMOUSE, 0, GCHandle.Alloc(mouseParams, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject(), SPIF.SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
```

Also [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978664.aspx) proved to be helpful.

Comment: I think you should make it `int[]` instead of `ref long[]`.

Comment: I think you would have a memory leak if you don't free the `GCHandle` instances you allocate - perhaps with some try/finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);
```

Shamelessly lifted from:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SystemParametersInfo.html

Comment: You're right. It seems I missed this one (I didn't want to get the memory address myself!)